# why an empty string can output index 0 element in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cout << s.size() << endl;
    cout << s[0] << endl;  //output empty line
    return 0;
}
```

As **s** is an empty string, why can it has an element **s[0]**? In my opinion, it should get a run time error. Is it a convention or anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a special rule that you can access `s[n]` where `n` is the length of `s`. The result is a null character (*i.e.* the value that results from value-initializing the character type) and attempting to modify it causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Is the rationale for this to make `s[n]` for a string act similar to a C-style string implemented as `char[n+1]`?

Comment: @Barmar I imagine it's something like that. The detailed rationale can probably be found somewhere but I'm too lazy to dig for it.

Comment: @Deduplicator, yes , it's §21.4.5 [string.access]

Comment: @quantdev: Seen. `s[s.size()]` may not be modified though, which is the only special rule about it.

Comment: Isn't it implementation-defined whether or not `std::string`'s buffer is null-terminated?